# How to dynamically update a variable by using mouse over?

Tags: dynamic

I want to extract the `Graphics` type when I hover my mouse over an object, but I failed to do so.
Below is the code I am working on. Any suggestions are welcome

```
m = "E";
Graphics[{ 
  Mouseover[ {Black, Disk[{-10, 0}]}, {m = "D"; Red, Disk[{-10, 0}]}],
  Mouseover[ {Black, Rectangle[{10, 0}]}, {m = "R"; Red, 
    Rectangle[{10, 0}]}]
  ,  Text[Dynamic[m], {0, 0}]
  }]
```

Comment: Have a look at `Annotation`, it appears that fits what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 4):

Use Dynamic inside Mouseover

```
Graphics[{
  Mouseover[{Black, Disk[{-10, 0}]}, Dynamic[{m = "D"; Red, Disk[{-10, 0}]}]],
  Mouseover[{Black, Rectangle[{10, 0}]}, Dynamic[{m = "R"; Red, Rectangle[{10, 0}]}]],
  Dynamic@Text[m, {0, 0}]
  }, ImageSize -> 400]
```

[image]